# Error in viewing workflow reports

Tags: workflow, reports

I have a workflow which seems to be problematic and when I run it I get

> "an error occured during approval".

To see more detailed error logs I clicked on **'view wrokflow reports'** in the workflow history section. But workflow reports itslef has a problem and I got this message: `"An unexpected error has occured. correlation id...".` When I follow its correlation id in SharePoint logs I find these messages:

> "failed to cache field with id ..."

or

> "value doesn't fall within expected range"

How can I solve the problem of workflow reports itself? How can I see error log of my workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

There were other errors in LOGs. One of them was

```
error loading the template {XYZ} for the activity duration
```

I searched for it error and found [this](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/Unable-to-access-audit-log-reports-on-a-team-site.html).

I deactivated 'reporting' feature at site collection level and activated it again.

Problem solved!

What a pity that sharepoint has such problems.

Comment: Could mark your own answer as "Accepted", please? That way it won't pop up in the "unanswered" statistic. Thanks.